# How to get webpage content into a string using Go

Tags: string, url, go

I am trying to use Go and the http package to get the content of a webpage into a string, then be able to process the string. I am new to Go, so I am not entirely sure where to begin. Here is the function I am trying to make.

```
func OnPage(link string) {

}
```

I am not sure how to write the function. Link is the url of the webpage to use, and result would be the string from the webpage. So for example, if I used reddit as the link, then the result would just be the string form of the content on reddit, and I could process that string in different ways. From what I have read, I want to use the http package, but as I stated before, I do not know where to begin. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can convert a `[]byte` directly to a `string` as needed

Answer (score 13):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)
func OnPage(link string)(string) {
    res, err := http.Get(link)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    content, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return string(content)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(OnPage("http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-38003934"))
}
```